# app loads but does not run

Tags: android

I have some free time and decided to try Android development.

Loaded ADT into windows 7 using the adt bundle.
Created an empty app named FirstApp.

Defined a virtual device of Android 4.2.2 named FirstApp.
Started the device scaled to size.
Selected "RUN" from ADT screen. .... got the following on console ...

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'firstapp' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
Uploading FirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing FirstApp.apk...
Failed to install FirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
(null)
Launch canceled!
```

I have no idea about what to do next.

jim murray

Comment: does the logcat contain anything else around those lines?

Answer (score 1):

quit all emulators and relaunch the project !
The, Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android and put 10000 on ADB connection and try to relaunch!

Comment: @jim murray : if my answer ask to your question, pleae click on the V of my answer, it could hlp someone else! thanks